# Reading animated GIFs SDL 2

Tags: c++, sdl-2

I would like to be able to load GIF animations instead of using sprite sheets and grids in a game I am working on. I believe this will make what I do much easier than now. I've looked it up on Google, but all I found was a library which uses Win32 calls; ergo restricted to Windows. I believe I can do the job if I figure out how I can extract the individual frames and delay values from an animated GIF. As the title says, I am using SDL2 to load my sprites.

Any kind of help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Edit: Oh and I am using C++.

Comment: So you're trying to figure out how to extract frames and values from an Animated GIF using SDL2. What have you tried so far? What language are you using?

Comment: :FACEPALM: I forgot to note that I am using C++. All I tried was loading a GIF with SDL_img which resulted in showing the 1st frame of the animations :/.I searched the internet a little bit and found a lib that does what I want by a guy called "doug". The problem with that is the fact that it uses win32 calls.

Comment: It isn't a job for `SDL_image`, it handles static image data. You should use `libungif` or `giflib` directly. (SDL_image uses custom GIF loader, but it doesn't handle animations). Or just reconsider your need for animated GIFs, maybe replacing it with image atlas.