# C++ SDL2 | How do I play a GIF in SDL2?

Tags: c++, sdl-2

I am aware that this topic has already been brought up, but I never could get anything out of the page. One clue to my answer was that I need to split up the GIF into each of its frames, but how? Some code along with this would be greatly appreciated. 
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Do you just need to play some animation in your game? Or you need GIF and only GIF?

Comment: To Holy Black Cat, What I intend to do is use a GIF file in conjunction with a sound file in order to create an effect that looks like a video cutscene. Yes, I am aware that this sounds very, VERY weird, but I was messing around with my game one day and I was like, what if I could do this? I know how to use spritesheets for basic animation so I don't need help with that. I am aware that you can play .avi video in SDL in conjunction with some other libraries, but those use SDL1. Also, I forgot to mention, would it be possible to play the GIF with all of the frames in one GIF file?

Comment: I haven't used GIF in my games, but I found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22708336/reading-animated-gifs-sdl-2 Some guy in comments says that you can use `libungif` or `giflib` for loading gifs. Try them.

Comment: To HolyBlackCat, Do you know of any tutorials that use these libraries? I haven't found any

Comment: Again, I haven't used GIF in my games. So, I know no tutorials.

Answer (score 2):

Use [GIFLIB](http://giflib.sourceforge.net) to read gif animations. GIFLIB provides a handy "slurp" function that reads the entire file into structs that you can then pretty easily retrieve your frames from. It's been a while but IIRC when building an `SDL_Texture` from the one gif frame you will need to look up colors from a palette for each pixel. Since gifs don't have one fixed frame rate you will also need to store the individual delay times for each frame. Read [this](http://giflib.sourceforge.net/whatsinagif/bits_and_bytes.html) for a detailed description of the gif file format and it will help you make sense of GIFLIB.

That said, I would advise against using the clunky GIF format for cutscenes (and most other things) because it's pretty space hungry and you may have problems syncing up your audio nicely. I would recommend looking around for a way to play "real" video formats -- take a look at [this project](https://github.com/pockethook/player).

Comment: Thanks a lot! This really helped me!